# What's the difference between ITCAM for Application Diagnostic and ITCAM for Websphere Application Server?

Tags: tivoli

Just as the time, what's the difference between ITCAM for Application Diagnostic and ITCAM for Websphere Application Server?

is the `ITCAM for Websphere Application Server just one part of`ITCAM for Application Dianostic`?

Please help explain it in detail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thats right, ITCAM for Websphere Application Server is ONE of the Agents inside the ITCAM for Application Diagnostics Product. ITCAM for AD includes also agents for J2EE, J2EE Data collectors and HTTP Servers.

You can find more details here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v24r1/index.jsp